# hystrix java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject.hasValue()Z

Tags: java, web-applications, rx-java, hystrix, netflix

I have one web application. the application is based on JSF. My application is not based on maven. It is using ant for the build. Recently I implemented the Hystrix circuit breaker in my application. It is working fine. I am getting "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject.hasValue()Z".
The same configuration is working in development. The details of the Hystrix is as following.

The library I am using is

```
archaius-core-0.4.1.jar
HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar
hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar
newrelic-api-2.21.4.jar
rxjava-1.2.0.jar
rxjava-core-0.20.3.jar
```

```html
############################################################################################################
# Hystrix Configuration
############################################################################################################

# Global Defaults
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=true
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=30000
hystrix.command.default.fallback.enabled=false
hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage=80

# Command/Group specific overrides
hystrix.command.lookup.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=30000



# Hystrix configuration ends
############################################################################################################
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject.hasValue()Z
        at com.netflix.hystrix.metric.consumer.BucketedCounterStream.getLatest(BucketedCounterStream.java:104)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommandMetrics.getHealthCounts(HystrixCommandMetrics.java:370)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreaker$HystrixCircuitBreakerImpl.isOpen(HystrixCircuitBreaker.java:188)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreaker$HystrixCircuitBreakerImpl.allowRequest(HystrixCircuitBreaker.java:161)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.applyHystrixSemantics(AbstractCommand.java:509)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.access$100(AbstractCommand.java:59)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$4.call(AbstractCommand.java:405)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$4.call(AbstractCommand.java:402)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:44)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:33)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:173)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:166)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:173)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:166)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:173)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:166)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:173)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:166)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8587)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:49)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:33)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:173)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:166)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8676)
        at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:55)
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:420)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:377)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:343)
        at com.intuit.ems.estore.EstoreServletAPIImpl.doExecuteRequestResilient(EstoreServletAPIImpl.java:356)
        at com.intuit.ems.estore.EstoreServletAPIImpl.getAccountInfo(EstoreServletAPIImpl.java:86)
        at com.intuit.ems.dispatch.DispatcherUtil.isQBRegistered(DispatcherUtil.java:174)
        at com.intuit.ems.buy.BuySwitchDesiredActionListener.exceptionQueuingBeforePhase(BuySwitchDesiredActionListener.java:86)
        at com.intuit.ems.adapter.common.ExceptionQueuingPhaseListener.beforePhase(ExceptionQueuingPhaseListener.java:41)
        ... 43 more
```

Comment: `rxjava-core-0.20.3.jar`? Try without it.

Comment: It worked 
Thanks
@akarnokd

Answer (score 0):

Just need to remove the "rxjava-core-0.20.3.jar" from dependency